# sql primary key of commutative columns

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is what I attempt to acheive :

I have one table `fabric` containing fabrics to build a product. When the administrator record a new fabric he can define if this fabric can be selected with another one (for compatibility of materials).

This exclusion relationship is commutative. If X doesn't go with Y, it means that Y can't go with X.

To implement that I created a table `fabric_exclusion` with two fields (`id_fabric1` and `id_fabric2`) forming a primary key.

But how can I have CRUD operations working with this underlaying logic `(id_fabric1=X|id_fabric2=Y) = (id_fabric1=Y|id_fabric2=X)` ?

**UPDATE:** Here is what I already tried :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PREFIX_fabric_exclusion` (
    `id_fabric1` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `id_fabric2` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `ids` UNIQUE (`id_fabric1`, `id_fabric2`),
    PRIMARY KEY `ids`
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Can you provide details about your fabric table?

Comment: I updated with the code I use to create my table. I tried to force UNIQUE on the 2 fields but I not sure if it means uniique in permutations.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a little overhead, but you could use a calculated field based on `id_fabric1` combined with  `id_fabric2` and a unique constraint (or even a primary key) on the calculated field. Thereby, it is ensured that, for example, a tuple `(4,3)` cannot be inserted if a tuple `(3,4)` exists and vice versa:

```
CREATE TABLE `PREFIX_fabric_exclusion` (
    `id_fabric1` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `id_fabric2` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    combinedKey int(21) as (if (id_fabric1 < id_fabric2, id_fabric1*100000000+ id_fabric2, id_fabric2*100000000+id_fabric1)) stored primary key
)

insert into PREFIX_fabric_exclusion(id_fabric1, id_fabric2) values (3, 4);

insert into PREFIX_fabric_exclusion(id_fabric1, id_fabric2) values (4, 3);  # Error: Duplicate entry '300000004' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Comment: But as Ryan Vincent pointed out this "much simpler" solution is not valid in MySql [my bad :-) ] This means that (my now deleted) approach would need to be implemented with a trigger, enforcing `id_fabric1 < id_fabric2.`

Comment: @Giorgos Altanis: I see :-) it is parsed but ignored. Adapted answer accordingly.

Comment: I like your approach, so I have upvoted. The only "issue" I have is that I think (from experience) that the condition `id1 < id2` is probably helpful in later development phases, and perhaps the developers would benefit from a view which guarantees this condition.

Comment: @Giorgos Altanis: I agree; but probably the application inserting tuples is not under the control of the DB designer, and a tuple like `(4,3)` is supposed to be valid. If not, the calculated expression could evaluate to `NULL` in this case, thereby yielding an error (PK attributes must not be `NULL')

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis : the first version was indeed much simpler :). 
@StephanLechner I tried out this one but it gives me an error `near 'as (if (id_fabric1 < id_fabric2, id_fabric1*100000000+ id_fabric2, id_fabric2*10'`

Answer (score 1):

I know I am probably late, And as I scratched my head through this, I found one viable solution to enforce this.

Usually, when you have such a commutative pair, the order doesn't really matter.

I started adding a BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `tbl_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `thread` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET @l = least(new.id1, new.id2);
SET @l2 = greatest(new.id1, new.id2);
SET new.id1 = @l;
SET new.id2 = @m;
END;
```

With this, you always insert in order and never have to violate it. Because, it essentially assigns the smaller one to one field, and the larger one to another. Since they're guaranteed to call in each row, you're almost as sure as an integrity constraint, but with some overhead. But, another interesting way I found is by having a pairing function, again, in the same way, but for commutativeness, I would say, I would use an unordered pairing function, but they're not as space efficient as these.

Comment: Thanks for your update. I don't have anything ready in order to test that. But I'll keep it for next time.